# How to identify download URL of apk

Tags: android, url, apk

I am writing an application where inside application wanted to identify from which URL-Source apk is download. Is there any way to get it.

Basically I wanted to know how many times apk is install from given URL.

Any suggestion here!!

Comment: You need to rethink your question, it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

> I am writing an application where I need to find download URL of apk. Is there any way to get it.

No, because there is no download URL. APKs are installed from local files. How the APK got to be a local file (downloaded from a URL, received in an email attachment, copied over to external storage via USB cable, etc.) is not something that you can determine.

> Basically I wanted to know how many times apk is install from given URL.

You are certainly welcome to use product flavors in Android Studio/Gradle for Android to create custom APKs based on distribution channel, where those APKs have a custom value baked into them (e.g., `buildConfigField` mapping to a `BuildConfig` field).

Comment: Thanks, u mean there is no other way except to set config-flavour and generate different apk. Basically application have sharing and get-reward feature, so if app install form shared-URL then user who has shared URL will get reward. Is there any way to do it !!

Comment: @Shubh: Not that I can think of, sorry.

Comment: no issue.. i think this is something use for same purpose...testing still remain..http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561636-How-Google-Play-Install-Referrer-Works